# How to customize/modify the default startup url in Mist brwoser for ERC20 tokens on Ethereum?

Tags: mist, tokens, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ico

Hi I am making an ICO wallet. I know Mist browser(https://github.com/ethereum/mist) has a lightweight version coming up soon and ConsenSys(https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet) has one, but I prefer using Mist codebase with a full node running...

So How can I customize/modify/change the default startup url(wallet.ethereum.org) in Mist brwoser to my own ERC20 token url(my Dapp frontend url) so it shows the token amount? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use Linux command $ grep -r "wallet.ethereum.org"

tests/_base.js:           url: 'https://wallet.ethereum.org',
tests/_base.js:           redirect: 'https://wallet.ethereum.org',

tests/mist/basic.test.js:    yield this.navigateTo('https://wallet.ethereum.org');
tests/mist/basic.test.js:    yield this.navigateTo(`${this.fixtureBaseUrl}index.html?https://wallet.ethereum.org`);
tests/mist/basic.test.js:    yield client.setValue('#url-input', `${this.fixtureBaseUrl}index.html?https://wallet.ethereum.org`);

interface/client/appStart.js: url: 'https://wallet.ethereum.org',
interface/client/appStart.js: redirect: 'https://wallet.ethereum.org',